# How can i convert the following bash script into a perl script

Tags: perl, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

i="0"

echo ""
echo "##################"
echo "LAUNCHING REQUESTS"
echo "  COUNT:  $2 "
echo "  DELAY:  $3 "
echo "  SESSID: $1"
echo "##################"
echo ""

while [ $2 -gt "$i" ]
do
  i=$[$i+1]
  php avtest.php $1 $4 &
  echo "EXECUTING REQUEST $i"
  sleep $3
done
```

here is a better/modified script in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

i="0"
#startTime=`date +%s`
startTime=$(date -u +%s)
startTime=$[$startTime+$1+5]
#startTime=$($startTime+$1+5)
dTime=`date -d @$startTime`
echo ""
echo "##################"
echo "LAUNCHING REQUESTS"
echo "  COUNT:  $1 "
echo "  DELAY:  1 "
#echo "  EXECUTION:  $startTime "
echo "  The scripts will fire at :  $dTime "
echo "##################"
echo ""

while [ $1 -gt "$i" ]
do
  i=$[$i+1]
  php avtestTimed.php $1 $3 $startTime &
  echo "QUEUEING REQUEST $i"
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Which bit is giving you trouble? And wouldn't it make more sense to convert to PHP and merge it with avtest.php so that you aren't spawning many, many processes?

Comment: i am stuck with perl since i am using rrdtool to plot the output. There might be a php API for RRDtool, but most of the examples are in perl

Comment: but there's nothing in this script which involves RRDtool; it's simply a launcher script. You could write it in any language.

Comment: correct, my reason is to have one script that does it all :) since this is a tool to be used by many people.

Comment: `startTime=$(($startTime + $1 + 5))` or `(( startTime += $1 + 5 ))` and `i=$((i + 1))` or `(( i++ ))` (double parentheses, not single)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a direct translation

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print <<HERE;
##################
LAUNCHING REQUESTS
  COUNT:  $ARGV[1]
  DELAY:  $ARGV[2]
  SESSID: $ARGV[0]
##################
HERE

my $i = 0;
while($ARGV[1] > $i){
    $i += 1;
    system("php avtest.php $ARGV[0] $ARGV[3] &");
    print "EXECUTING REQUEST $i\n";
    sleep $ARGV[2];
}
```

But it would make more sense to read the command line parameters into variables named after what they're for and not rely on remembering argument ordering.

A brief errata in the conversion:

I use a here string to represent multiline text. I could also have put in multiple `print` statements to more closely mimic the bash version

In bash arguments are accessed as numbered variables, starting with $1 and going up. In Perl the argument list is represented by the array @ARGV, which is numbered starting at zero (like arrays in most languages). In both bash and Perl the name of the script can be found in the variable $0.

In Perl arrays are written as `@arrayname` when refering to the entire array, but they use $arrayname[index] when accessing array members. So the Perl `$list[0]` is like the bash `${list[0]}` and the Perl `@list` is like the bash `${list[@]}`.

In Perl variables are declared with the `my` keyword; the equivalent in bash would be `declare`.

I've used the `system` function for spawning background processes. Its argument can be simply the command line as you might use it in bash.

Unlike `echo`, `print` requires to be told if there should be a newline at the end of the line. For recent versions of Perl the `say` function exists which will append a newline for you.

The Perl `sleep` function is pretty self-explanatory.

EDIT: Due to a typo `$i` in the print statement had been represented as `$ni` leading to runtime errors. This has been corrected.

Comment: here is the error: <pre> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./loadAVTimed.pl line 17.
EXECUTING REQUEST 1
Argument "ssotest.yakabod.net" isn't numeric in sleep at ./loadAVTimed.pl line 19.
 </pre>

Comment: That sounds like it's being run with the wrong arguments.  What did it print as the "DELAY:"?

Comment: @kamal: The first error was due to a typo. I have edited the above code to correct it. The second error is correctly diagnosed by Gordon.

Comment: ./loadAVTimed.pl 10 0 example.httpshostname.com, where 10 is supposed to be the number of requests (COUNT) and 0 being the delay, but it seems to be reversed

Comment: actually now i just noticed that the DELAY is actually getting ARG[2] which is the hostname

Comment: updated the script, kept the old one as well for comparison. I would appreciate of you could comment, or translate

Comment: According to your bash script $3 is delay, which is the third argument. In Perl this corresponds to $ARGV[2], which is the third index in to the array (starting with 0). If this was not working for you then your original example script was not correct either. If 10 was your count and 0 your delay, then you seem to have omitted `$1` aka `$ARGV[0]`, which was the session ID.